# Protractor error Angular could not be found on the page

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to set up End-2-End testing for my Angular (1.4) site using protractor (2.1.0).  Jasmine is installed and unit tests are working fine.  When I run protractor the index#/login page loads in a browser window but no code runs and protractor reports this error

> Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost/SpectrumGMWeb/index.html#/login : retries looking for angular exceeded

My protractor config looks like this

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: [
        '*.js'
    ],
    rootElement:'html',
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost/SpectrumGMWeb/',
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },
};
```

My test file is very simple

```
describe('my app', function() {

    describe('login', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
            browser.get('index.html#/login');
        });

        it('should render login page when user navigates to login page', function() {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });

    });
});
```

ng-app="main" is set on the html element of index.html.  The website does work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just for the sake of testing and debugging, move `ng-app` to `body` and comment out `rootElement` in the config. Same error? Thanks.

Comment: also tried... renaming root module, and manually bootstrapping angular

Comment: Do you have the correct login page url in the get method `browser.get('index.html#/login')`? Does the number sign `#` belong there? If it does then you might have some redirection to an intermediate non-angular page going on.

Comment: Try this: **browser.driver.get('index.html#/login');**

Comment: I tried browser.get('index.html') but same problem.  I tried browser.driver.get but then the browser through an error "Cannot navigate to invalid URL"

Comment: Tried using absolute paths in my index.html.  didn't help

Comment: Your you are definitely on an angular page, your login form isn't from an external source or something?

Comment: Nope, its an all angular SPA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well thanks everyone for your input.  I did finally fix this problem by copying all the index.html file contents to a new file.  It seems that somehow the file was corrupted in a way that protractor did not like.  I know it sounds simple but I wasted 2 full days on this so hope it helps someone.

Comment: This actually turned out to be a problem with the file encoding.  The index page got Unicode encoded somehow but had the setting <meta charset="utf-8" />

Answer (score 10):

Try putting a `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` before you do a `browser.get()` in your login function.

Comment: This will get rid of the error but isn't a solution to the problem as this setting will cause problems with tests later on.

Comment: The setting can be enabled back after this particular function `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false`. Also, as long as login function is in a different library, ignoring synchronization will not affect the test later on.

Comment: That is true, and this would be a valid answer if the login page wasnt within the angular app, but in the example given the login page is an angular page so ignoreSync shouldn't be necessary there is probably a problem with the way angular is configured, this could potentially mask another problem.

Comment: Yes. I agree it is not a direct answer, but it is the one that can solve the problem. I am sure there can be many plausible explanations as to why the page is behaving this way. I too had the same issue on the login page and this how i solved my problem without side effects on the rest of the test.

Comment: I have the same problem but i couldn't resolve it with your options, any other suggestions?

Comment: If above option is not working you can try this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752301/protractor-error-angular-could-not-be-found-on-the-page/48542613#48542613

Answer (score 8):

If you need to navigate to a page which does not use Angular then Add this line of code before browser.get() line there:

browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

Reference : https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've launched your server at `http://localhost/SpectrumGMWeb/`?

Protractor is feeding this URL to Selenium and trying to access your application at this address. If it is not running at this address Protractor will get no response from it and will give you the error you are getting.

If you need advice on how to get a local server up and running to serve your project, I recommend [grunt-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect), for example like this (which will launch a server at `http://localhost:9001`)

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    base: '', // root folder of your app files
                     keepalive: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect:server'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this error as well, and I fixed it by changing my package.json "scripts" variable from:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  }
```

to

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    // REMOVE "pree2e"
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```