# Travis+Protractor Error: Angular could not be found on the page

Tags: angular, protractor, travis-ci

I'm brand new to Protractor and I'm having trouble running the tests of [my app](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-angular2-example) on Travis CI. It gives me this error:

> [22:54:04] E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page
>   http://localhost:4200/about : retries looking for angular exceeded
>   About
>       ✗ should have correct feature heading
>         - Failed: Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:4200/about.If this is not an Angular application, you
>   may need to turn off waiting for Angular.

My [test file](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-angular2-example/blob/master/e2e/about.e2e-spec.ts) contains

```
describe('About', () => {

  beforeEach(async () => {
    return await browser.get('/about');
  });

  it('should have correct feature heading', () => {
    expect(element(by.css('rio-about-page h2')).getText()).toEqual('ABOUT US');
  });

});
```

My [travis.yml](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-angular2-example/blob/master/.travis.yml) file contains this

```
script:
 - ng test --watch false
 - npm run prod:server &
 - npm run prod:client &
 - npm run e2e
```

and [package.json](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-angular2-example/blob/master/package.json) contains

```
"prod:client": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
"prod:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production PORT=3000 node server/node-server.js",
"e2e": "protractor",
```

It runs properly locally if I start up the app and api servers first. So it seems like the test just needs to wait until the api and app servers are ready, but I'm not sure how to make that happen.

I tried setting framework to "jasmine2" from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497906/failed-error-while-waiting-for-protractor-to-sync-with-the-page-angular-could), but it didn't work.

I also checked the encoding of my `index.html` file according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752301/protractor-error-angular-could-not-be-found-on-the-page) and it was fine.

I also locally tried changing the e2e command in travis.yml to

```
ng e2e --serve
```

This gave me the following warnings. The tests did not run and the process did not terminate

> webpack: Compiled with warnings. (node:20625)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot find module
>   'protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cmds/update' from
>   '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/gba' (node:20625) DeprecationWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
>   rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
>   with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md

Comment: @Gunderson That did it. Thanks!! I hadn't seen that setting used in any of the examples and my app didn't seem special but I guess its being bigger than the examples mattered. Besides that setting, do my travis.yml and package.json scripts look okay? I'm happy it's working now but it seems that `ng e2e` should work.

Comment: Glad it helped!  Unfortunately I have no experience with Travis or Angular CLI, so I can't speak to that config =/ sorry